# Rails & Acts-as-versioned: How would you restfully revert records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, acts-as-versioned

How can you revert records in a way that respects REST conventions and routing?

I am looking for examples of how to setup my routes.rb and build the link & controller action to do the revert.  All the examples I have found are pre-REST rails.

My understanding is that I need to have  revert_to_version function in my resource controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've never used acts-as-versioned in particular, but when I come across similar scenarios, the way I usually solve it is by reification of the attribute.
In other words, I'd create a new resource only for the actual version number of the resource.

Eg.

```
/resources/:id/actual_version
```

would point to the actual version number of the resource with id :id.
Then to change the actual version, we can just PUT desired number to it.

```
PUT /resources/:id/actual_version
:version = 123
```

would revert our resource to the version 123.

As a convention, I'd use something like "last-but-one" as a value of :version to refer to the version that preceded the actual one.

Then, to rollback the actual version, we can just do:

```
PUT /resources/:id/actual_version
:version=last-but-one
```

--

Expanding my own answer:

In routes.rb we can do something like:

```
  map.connect   '/resources/:id/actual_version', :controller => 'resources', :action => 'set_version', :conditions => { :method => :put }
```

And in resources_controller.rb:

```
def set_version
  @resource = Resource.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if params[:version] && @resource
    version = params[:version] == "last-but-one" ? @resource.versions.last : params[:version]
    if @resource.revert_to(version)
      # Success, everything went fine!
    else
      # Error, the resource couldn't be reverted - unexisting version?
    end
  else
    # Error, version number or resource id is missing.
  end
end
```

Hope that clarified my previous thoughts a bit. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're rolling your own system. My answer does not relate to any particular versioning plugin.

Because your URLs are paths to resources, I would consider the revision parameter as optional. You can leave it out, and get the latest revision, or specify the revision eplicitly.

```
GET /pages/1
GET /pages/1?revision=4
```

Same goes for editing.

```
GET /pages/1/edit
GET /pages/1/edit?revision=4
```

PUT to /pages/1 would create a new revision, incrementing the version number by one. The new version number is created without regard to the current revision number. It's merely a starting point when editing.

Obviously, it should be impossible to specify a revision for a POST to /pages (create).

If you want to track reverts in particular, and the editing starting point mentioned above isn't sufficient, there are a few sensible alternatives. I'm not a REST geek, so I'm not sure which you should choose. Perhaps it's a matter of taste.

```
PUT /pages/1/revisions/4
PUT /pages/1/revert_to?revision=4
PUT /pages/1?revision=4
```

A code example for the first alternative:

```
# config/routes.rb
map.resources :pages do |page|
  page.resources :revisions
end

# app/controllers/revisions_controller.rb
class RevisionsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @page = Page.find(params[:page_id]) # page_id is via /pages/[page_id]/revisions/4
    @revision = @page.revisions.find_by_version_number(params[:id])
    @revision.revert
  end
end

# app/models/revision.rb
class Revision < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page

  def revert
    page.revert_to(self) # or something like that..
  end
end
```

If you roll with this, it probably makes sense to GET /pages/1/revisions/4 to display the page for revision 4, instead of GET /pages/1?revision=4.